# Nodejs block increasing by time then halts application - pool.getConnection sync block

Tags: mysql, node.js, asynchronous, blocking

My nodejs application expreriences increasing blocking over time and finally blocks totally and halts. This means 1 total block per day when it needs to restart. Inspected everything, installed blocked-at. What is see is usually the same section:

```
Blocked for 375.48965625ms, operation started here: [ '    at Socket.connect (net.js:1012:40)',
  '    at Object.connect (net.js:107:35)',
  '    at PoolConnection.connect (/var/www/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:91:13)',
  '    at Pool.getConnection (/var/www/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/Pool.js:48:16)',
  '    at /var/www/app/nodeapp/ws.js:371:11',
  '    at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (fs.js:528:3)' ]
```

It seems pool connect syncronously blocks nodejs it goes up to 1500 ms and beacomes very often, until it totally halts the application. Cant figure out what could be the problem. pool.getconnection is async.
It is a webpage with chat, total about 500 users online checked mysql, node pool everything seems fine and the application is very fast except when it hangs for these blocks which increase by time.

Comment: something written inside your callback might be the thing which blocks

Comment: might want to take a look at this: https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql/issues/405

Comment: this is a pool.getConnection callback which is followed immediately by another callback: users.getMessages which is a mysql query (immediately starts whith the query). So it could not block synchronously, unless blocked-at is wrong showing the wrong place of block, and the block comes much later, after 2 async mysql queries are executed and i process user data. But i guess then blocked-at should report the last callback, where the sync process starts. I will check that out and place my own timer at the last callback to measure sync process time.

Comment: i have checked that link, it seems similar but it hangs, while mine goes on just blocks. i experience blocking over 400 clients which becomes frequent above 500 clients. It is something related to client numbers. Also checked nodejs source cod for reafFileAfterClose but nothing special is there.